# prevAll on hidden elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

Hi i have a hidden div which inside hold other divs

Example

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="o-1">...<div>
    <div>...<div>
    <div>...<div>
    <div id="o-2">...<div>
    <div>...<div>
    <div>...<div>
    <div id="o-3">...<div>
    <div>...<div>
    <div>...<div>
   </div>
```

I am trying to get the prevAll of div id="o-3" which id starts whith o-
In the above example the prevAll of o-3 are o-2 and o-1

The problem is that because the wrapper div is hidden i can get the preAll

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: What selector have you tried?

Comment: @Abhilash  $("#o-3").prevAll("div[id^='o-']");

Comment: .prevAll() works for hidden elements. What do you plan to do to the elements?

Comment: Can you fix your invalid HTML? Can you better show us what are you trying to do? That selector should normally work. Unless you are misusing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't seem to have any problems selecting hidden elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/U2YPB/2/

```
$.each($("#ho3").prevAll(),function(idx,div) {
    log($(div).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that the parent is set to be hidden, the element is still in your DOM.

Instead, one problem is that your HTML is a bit messed up. You aren't closing your `<div>` elements properly.

From your code:

```
<div>...<div>
```

Should be:

```
<div>...</div>
```

You could then use this to get the previous siblings that has an id that starts with `o-`:

```
$("#o-3").prevAll("[id^='o-']")
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/z5nHF/)

Comment: +1 for testing code, but the problem wan not the html code even if i wrote it wrong (i created a dummy code and mess it up with copy-paste).Thanks for your reply i was helpful  (trigger my mind)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$('div:third').prevAll(':hidden');
```

or you can directly user

```
$("#o-3").prevAll("div[id^='o-']");
```